# Is GotW #47 halfly wrong?

Tags: c++

[GotW #47](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm)

> **The Wrong Solution**
>
> "Aha," many people -- including many experts -- have said, "let's use uncaught_exception() to figure out whether we can throw or not!" And that's where the code in Question 2 comes from... it's an attempt to solve the illustrated problem:

```
//  The wrong solution
//
T::~T() {
  if( !std::uncaught_exception() ) {
    // ... code that could throw ...
  } else {
    // ... code that won't throw ...
  }
}
```

> The idea is that "we'll use the path that could throw as long as it's safe to throw." This philosophy is wrong on two counts: first, this code doesn't do that; second (and more importantly), the philosophy itself is in error.
>
> **The Wrong Solution: Why the Code Is Unsound**
>
> One problem is that the above code won't actually work as expected in some situations. Consider:

```
//  Why the wrong solution is wrong
//
U::~U() {
  try {
    T t;
    // do work
  } catch( ... ) {
    // clean up
  }
}
```

> If a U object is destroyed due to stack unwinding during to exception propagation, T::~T will fail to use the "code that could throw" path even though it **safely could**.

I believe that explanation above is completely incorrect, if std::uncaught_exception returns true it is **ALWAYS** unsafe to let any function including destructor to exit with another exception. [Prove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw)

> If any function that is called during stack unwinding, after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler, exits with an exception, std::terminate is called. Such functions include destructors of objects with automatic storage duration whose scopes are exited, and the copy constructor of the exception object that is called (if not elided) to initialize catch-by-value arguments.

Same words in c++ (terminate is called in ~YYY()):

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct YYY
    {
        ~YYY()
        {
            std::cout << "during stack unwinding before throwing second exception " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
            throw std::exception();
        }
    };
    struct XXX
    {
        ~XXX()
        {
            std::cout << "after first exception thrown but not catched " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
            if (std::uncaught_exception())
            {
                try
                {
                    YYY yyy;
                }
                catch (const std::exception&)
                {
                    std::cout << "in second exception catch block " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    try
    {
        XXX xxx;
        std::cout << "before throwing first exception " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
        throw std::exception();
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        std::cout << "in first exception catch block " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "after both exceptions catched " << std::uncaught_exception() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is did I miss something and Herb Sutter is right for some specific case or he is absolutely wrong in this piece of the explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a question of what is meant by "any function that is called during stack unwinding" in the standard text.

I believe the intent was to prevent "any function that is called **directly** by the stack unwinding mechanism" to terminate with an exception, i.e. to throw another (new) exception into the active stack unwinding session. This requirement is not supposed to apply to any subsequent (nested) functions calls made *internally* by any function that is called by the original stack unwinding session.

As long as new exceptions are thrown and caught internally, without being allowed to escape into the active stack unwinding session, they are allowed. Herb's explanation is in full agreement with the standard: it is possible to throw new exceptions during stack unwinding as long as they are intercepted and suppressed internally.

Your example calls `terminate()` for a different reason. You are probably compiling with post-C++11 compiler. In C++11 destructors are `noexpect` by default, which is why your `YYY::~YYY()` simply calls `terminate()` regardless of whether stack unwinding is in progress, or of any other external conditions (GCC will even warn you about exactly that).

Declare it as

```
~YYY() throw(std::exception) // or `noexcept(false)`
{
  ...
```

to test the intended behavior of the code. And no, it does not call `terminate()`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/296ffb43b774409e

Herb's outdated code, obviously, suffers from the same problem.

Comment: I do agree with the explanation why ~YYY in my example called terminate. I just don't understand what you mean by "any function that is called directly by the stack unwinding mechanism". Can you provide c++ example what you mean? Other words, I don't understand why it is ok from the standard point of view if I add noexcept(false) to the ~YYY why it does not call terminate?